RxJS Create two observables from one obseravable
I have this:
$someObserver
   .subscribe(foo => {
      if(foo === "Bar" ) {/*Do A*/}
      else {/*Do B*/}
});

It works. What I want: achieving the same but without conditions and with more RxJS style.
Is there something to do it RxJS style?
I know 'partition' but i dont like it. I would prefer to the separation within the stream. Something like:
$someObserver
.pipe(
   split(foo => foo === 'bar') 
      tap([streamA, stream] => {
         streamA.subscribe(x => /*doA*/);
         streamB.subscribe(x => /* doB */) ;
})).subscribe();

Does something like this exists?
Thanks!

Can I use partition without creating two variables?

If you want to do basic non observable actions, just use a tap.
import './style.css';

import { rx, of, map, from, tap } from 'rxjs';

const arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2];

from(arr)
  .pipe(
    tap((item: number) => {
      if (item === 1) {
        console.log(1);
      } else {
        console.log(2);
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

Stackblitz Demo

If you have observable actions also, consider iif instead, for splitting the streams based on a condition.
import './style.css';

import { rx, of, map, from, concatMap, iif, tap } from 'rxjs';

const arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2];

from(arr)
  .pipe(
    concatMap((item: number) => iif(
      () => item === 1,
      of(item).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log(1))
      ),
      of(item).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log(2))
      )
    ))
  )
  .subscribe();

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks. The second example interests me. But do I have to unsubscribe 3 times at the end of my component because I created 3 observables?

@jaheraho No just one unsubscribe, for the subscribe at the end

@jaheraho The entire flow is a single stream, so there needs to be only one unsubscribe
